# Pullback of the Poincare bundle over Abelian varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Fix an Abelian variety $A$ and consider the Poincare line bundle $P_A$ over $A\times A^t$ where $A^t$ be the dual Abelian variety. Then show that $([m]\times[n])^*P_A=P_A^{\otimes mn}$.

Why? I lift this to the Mumford bundle and don't know how to show it! One can show that
$$([m]\times[n])^*\Lambda(L)=m^*[mn]^*(L)\otimes pr_1^*[m]^*L^{-1}\otimes pr_2^*[n]^*L^{-1},$$
As there exists $K_i\in Pic^0(A)$ such that $[mn]^*L\cong L^{m^2n^2}\otimes K_1$ and $[m]^*L^{-1}\cong L^{-m^2}\otimes K_2$ and $[n]^*L^{-1}\cong L^{-n^2}\otimes K_3$. Maybe when we descend them to $A\times A^t$, then these $K_i$ will be vanish! But there are $m^*,pr_j^*$ outside! So I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your any help!